# installing vmware-tools for windows guest

Tags: installation, vmware

i have downloaded the required file `vmware-tools-windows-9.2.3-1031769.x86_64.component.tar` but i don't understand how to install it. It untars to `vmware-tools-windows-9.2.3-1031769.x86_64.component` and `descriptor.xml`.How do i install a `.component` file?

the host is raring ringtail and the guest is windows 8 in vmware player. Also under the ubuntu environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This workaround worked for me:

http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?62913-Workarounds-for-installing-VMware-Player-in-13-04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please note that only sending a link is discouraged in our community. It is better to write a short abstract because the link may not work in the future rendering you answer useless.

Answer (score 1):

Latest vmware-player version (6.0.2) is able to download and install the vmware-tools for all guest platforms supported automatically but I need to install vmware-tools in the guest manually from ISO image to a virtual CD in the Windows guest. The image location in Linux `/usr/lib/vmware/isoimages`